# Typescript + webpack module resolution

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I am having an issue with webpack/typescript correctly resolving modules.
Consider the below structure

```
Project files
src/models/item.ts

Dependencies
node_modules/@common/src/models/item.ts
node_modules/@common/src/models/container.ts
```

The @common module contains common libraries, that each project can use and extend base on its needs.
What I am trying to accomplish is that when the container.ts imports item.ts as

```
import item from "models/item";
```

Webpack should resolve the path to the project's path.
However, I am getting the one from the @common path

Below is the relevant part from CRA's ejected webpack config and the relevant tsconfig

webpack config

```
resolve: {
  // This allows you to set a fallback for where webpack should look for modules.
  // We placed these paths second because we want `node_modules` to "win"
  // if there are any conflicts. This matches Node resolution mechanism.
  // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/253
  modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules, "./src", "node_modules/@common/src"].concat(
    modules.additionalModulePaths || []
  ),
```

tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
        "*": ["*", "src/*", "../node_modules/@common/src/*"]
    },
```

I would expect this to be possible.
Am I missing something?

Thanks for any help